# Catch Exception from replace method in powershell v5

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to write a script to find and replace a string in a file. How do I catch an exception if the script fails to replace the string for some reason and log it in an external file? Here is what I have so far.

```
Write-Host "Checking Execution Policy"

$currentExecutionPolicy = Get-ExecutionPolicy
    if( $currentExecutionPolicy -eq "RemoteSigned")
        {
            Write-Host "Execution policy check passed"
        } 
    else 
        {
            "Setting Execution policy to RemoteSigned as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Execution_Policies"
            Set-ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned
        }

Write-Host "Starting Script"

#Recurse through all the file shares and find the file.
$rootPath='\\do.main.name\shared\Information Technology\IT\u.name'
    $hotspotFile = Get-ChildItem -Path $rootPath -Recurse -Include "hotspot.mac" 
     Write-Host "Found file" $hotspotFile
     $logstring = "Found file" + $hotspotFile
     WriteLog $logstring

       try
       {
         (Get-Content $hotspotFile).Replace("olddomain.com","do.main.name") | Set-Content $hotspotFile    

       }
       catch
       {

        Write-Host "Failed to replace string -" $file
        $logstring = "Failed to replace string -" + $file
        WriteLog $logstring
       }


#Logging
$Logfile = "F:\u.name\Documents\Logs\SCR_To_Find_And_Replace_Old_Domain_String.log"

Function WriteLog
{
   Param ([string]$logstring)

   Add-content $Logfile -value $logstring
}
```

Comment: In what way does this script not meet your expectations?

Comment: Also, you would be better off using Write-Verbose rather than Write-Host. See http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/

Comment: Sorry probably should have mentioned it in the question. It fails to throw an error when it actually doesn't find the string in that file.

Comment: Not finding the string to replace is not an exception. The script will need to test to see if the string is in the file.

Comment: Also, Set-ExecutionPolicy only need to be done once. It should not be in every script. Besides, it will not work unless it is running as Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments. Checking if the string exist after doing the replacement would work too. But why wouldn't it raise an exception?

Comment: Replace() did its job without error. It replaced "a" with "b". Just because "a" was not there to be replaced does not represent a failure.

Comment: Excellent  logic. Thanks

Comment: @null + 1 for choosing an awesome username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, I think a failed replace does not generate an exception so you can't use try catch.

Instead you could use an if test, e.g.:

```
If ($hotspotfile -notcontains "do.main.name") { }
```

Or test the file for the presence of the old string. You'd probably be wise to also put in an earlier if statement testing if the string was present in the file in the first place and skipping the replace and check if it wasn't.